# Grid search problems with SVC - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to find the best hyperparameters for [Support Vector classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). So far, [Grid Search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) worked fine for tasks like that, but with the SVCs it seems to be hitting walls everywhere.

A minimal attempt with only a few suggestions for the `C` parameter works and produces results:

```
param_grid = {
    'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
}
classifier = SVC()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='f1', 
                           error_score=0, n_jobs=-1, verbose=42)
grid_search.fit(data[0], np.ravel(data[1]))
```

Similarly, other parameters like `gamma`, `coef0` or `shrinking` don't create any problems.

However, anything involving searching for a kernel function just seems to go on processing infinitely. Even just adding one other choice leads to Python hogging all available processors for some ominous work that does not finish (at least not within 10 minutes or so).

```
param_grid = {
    'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
    'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
}
```

What's really confusing me is that it starts out alright, producing good output within the first minute, then just seemingly stops doing anything while still making the coolers run in full speed. The verbose output looks like this:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 8 candidates, totalling 24 fits
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.01 ..............................................
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.01 ..............................................
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.01 ..............................................
[CV] kernel=linear, C=0.01 ...........................................

[...]/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1113: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)

[CV] ............... kernel=rbf, C=0.01, score=0.564932, total=   0.9s
[CV] kernel=linear, C=0.01 ...........................................
[CV] ............... kernel=rbf, C=0.01, score=0.574120, total=   0.8s
[CV] kernel=linear, C=0.01 ...........................................
[CV] ............... kernel=rbf, C=0.01, score=0.000000, total=   0.9s
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.1 ...............................................

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    1.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 tasks      | elapsed:    1.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 tasks      | elapsed:    1.5s

[CV] ................ kernel=rbf, C=0.1, score=0.555556, total=   1.0s
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.1 ...............................................

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    2.9s

[CV] ................ kernel=rbf, C=0.1, score=0.564932, total=   1.1s
[CV] kernel=rbf, C=0.1 ...............................................

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   5 tasks      | elapsed:    4.5s

[CV] ................ kernel=rbf, C=0.1, score=0.574120, total=   1.0s
[CV] kernel=linear, C=0.1 ............................................

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   6 tasks      | elapsed:    5.9s
```

Setting `njobs` to any other number leads to similar results: A part of the computation is done quickly and without complaints, then it seems to get stuck and uses all available CPU without any visible progress.

Furthermore, giving only one kernel choice has different results. While `rbf` and `sigmoid` work fine and finish within seconds, `poly` and `linear` apparently get stuck.

I'm at a loss - **what is the problem here, and how can I run grid search usefully**? My `data` consists of a bit over 5000 instances with 12 numerical features each. The classes are either 0 or 1, in equal distribution. Is that too much, maybe? If so, why would some searches work just fine and the trouble only start for certain kernel functions?

**EDIT** It looks like this is a problem with the data I'm using. The only thing that helped, so far, was normalizing the features (all values in a range from 0 to 1).

Now, normalization is generally recommended for Support Vector approaches, as they are not scale invariant, so I was going for it in any case. But I thought of it as a way to improve performance, not a necessary precaution for it to work, like it seems to be in this case.

I'll be able to work with this, for now, but I'm still curious whether anybody knows just what might be wrong with the data and how it could stil be fed to a support vector algorithm.

Comment: The volume of your data is not great, so it shouldn't be an issue. Is your data separable? Do the features capture that separability correctly? If not, then it would make sense that for large `C`s it takes so much time [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel)

Comment: I don't know whether the data is separable. Likely not, at least not very well, though SVC has had some successes on some isolated parts of the data so far. Restricting the parameter to only `'C' : [0.001]` leads to the same problems with a linear kernel function, though ... it went through four configurations then stopped producing output but is still using almost all CPU resources.

Comment: ugh debugging this will not be easy unfortunately... What kind of accuracy have you seen so far?

Comment: My grid search utilizes f1 for choosing the best classifier. The best score I've found has been 0.61328588575 for `SVC(C=10, kernel='rbf', ...)`, running grid search on all training data. When I test this best classifier on some remaining test data, I achieve about 71 percent accuracy.

Comment: Can you upload your data and a minimal complete example to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't hand out the data, as it does not belong to me. It's about 5000 x 12 numerical values, not normalized yet (that would have been the next step after running grid search on the pure data), thus in different ranges from about -30 to 30 to about -3000 to 3000.

Comment: @danny Thanks for the details, the accuracy seems low but it might be irrelevant to the actual issue and it is not possible to tell more without data. If you check the `if __name__=='__main__':` solution that sera provided (or any of the solutions mentioned), please let us know if it worked or not? It could just be it..

Comment: @mkaran Unfortunately, the solution did not work. But I experimented with the data a bit and updated the question with the insights. In short: After normalizing everything seems to work, so it probably is a problem within my data. One I'm not sure how to fix, but at least there might be a workaround here.

Answer (score 1):

I used my data and I modified a bit you code. It runs fine the following code for me in Windows 8.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC


if __name__=='__main__':

    data= pd.read_csv('Prior Decompo2.csv', header=None)
    X, y = data.iloc[0:, 0:26].values, data.iloc[0:,26].values

    param_grid = {'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'kernel': ('rbf', 'linear')}
    classifier = SVC()
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, verbose=42)
    grid_search.fit(X,y)
```

**Change #1:**

I added the `if __name__=='__main__':`

**Change #2:**

Use parenthesis for the `kernel`:

```
param_grid = {'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10], 'kernel': ('rbf', 'linear')}
```

*Important:*

In your code that you posted after `'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],` you have a comma that is not needed at all !

**Change #3:**

Inside `GridSearchCV` use another scoring e.g. `scoring='accuracy'`:

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, verbose=42)
```

**The results is:**

[image]

**You can clearly see in the image that both `linear` and `rbf` are tested.**

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I want! But the solution does not work for me. Were you able to reproduce the error before introducing the steps? So far, it really looks like it might have to do with the data. I've made sure all my libraries have the latest version. I've tried running the script through an IDE (instead of a notebook). I changed systems and ran the script on a Mac and a Windows machine, same result. The only thing that helped, so far, was normalizing the features. All kernels run smoothly with data in the range 0-1, execution is quick and stable.

Comment: @danny before introducing my steps and using my data, I was getting an error about the scoring='f1' so when I changed to scoring='accuracy' it worked fine for my data. Can you do the same and let me know ? If this does not work for you, the error has something to do with your data. Also make sure you used the change #2 that I posted !

Comment: I implemented all your changes, separately and all at once, no combination worked for me.

Comment: @danny then I guess it's something wrong with your data.. Is it bad if you normalize your features? if not, then just normalize and you solved your problem

Comment: Yes, it seems like that is the cause. It's not necessarily bad (it was a direction into which I had planned to go anyway), but I'd have preferred to test the stuff on the original data first. It might be interesting to try and find out what it is about the data that bugs certain kernel functions so much, but I'm not sure there will be time for that. Thanks for now, this really helped me look at the problem from all angles!

Comment: @danny sure. let as know